# Pandas : NaN value is assigned to a column even when indexes are exactly same

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, split, series

I have a dataframe that contains datetime values. I was trying to assign the result of split to my columns but I see that NaN values are assigned even when indexes are exactly same.

###### Data

```
data = {'date': ['2015-01-02', '2015-01-02', '2015-01-02', '2015-01-02'], 'time': ['09:30:00', '09:35:00', '09:55:00', '10:00:00'], 'val': [64.815, 64.8741, 65.0255, 64.9269]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
```

##### Some pre-processing

```
df['datetime'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date'] + ' ' + df['time'])
df.set_index('datetime', inplace=True)
df = df.resample('5min').asfreq().reindex(pd.date_range('2015-01-02 09:30:00', '2015-01-02 10:05:00', freq='5 min')).ffill()
```

##### The line that gives me NaN values

```
df[['date', 'time']] = df.index.astype(str).to_series().str.split(' ', expand=True)
```

which gives me

```
df
                    date time      val
2015-01-02 09:30:00  NaN  NaN  64.8150
2015-01-02 09:35:00  NaN  NaN  64.8741
2015-01-02 09:40:00  NaN  NaN  64.8741
2015-01-02 09:45:00  NaN  NaN  64.8741
2015-01-02 09:50:00  NaN  NaN  64.8741
2015-01-02 09:55:00  NaN  NaN  65.0255
2015-01-02 10:00:00  NaN  NaN  64.9269
2015-01-02 10:05:00  NaN  NaN  64.9269
```

I am not sure why am I getting Nan values even when indexes are same

Answer (score 3):

Assign the `values` not the dataframe to your original df, since assignment sub-df must have same columns name to prevent NaN

```
df[['date', 'time']] = df.index.astype(str).to_series().str.split(' ', expand=True).values
df
Out[761]: 
                           date      time      val
2015-01-02 09:30:00  2015-01-02  09:30:00  64.8150
2015-01-02 09:35:00  2015-01-02  09:35:00  64.8741
2015-01-02 09:40:00  2015-01-02  09:40:00  64.8741
2015-01-02 09:45:00  2015-01-02  09:45:00  64.8741
2015-01-02 09:50:00  2015-01-02  09:50:00  64.8741
2015-01-02 09:55:00  2015-01-02  09:55:00  65.0255
2015-01-02 10:00:00  2015-01-02  10:00:00  64.9269
2015-01-02 10:05:00  2015-01-02  10:05:00  64.9269
```

Comment: can you update the method where I can rename the columns in the same line